# What does "21 not fitting sprities try multipacking" in TexturePacker refer to?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, texturepacker

I just picked up TexturePacker and I dragged my images folder to the window that says, Drag Folder Here. And then all of my images load into this cool image sheet but then I get an error message at the bottom of the screen that says, "21 not fitting sprites - try multipacking, Size: 2048x2048 (16384kB)"

The reason I got TexturePacker is to optimize the graphics in my app. I do have about 48 full size images (1024 x 768) in the file. I'm guessing this is what it refers to. But I can't find any documentation on the TexturePacker site. Any one have similar issues? How should I treat my larger images. There's no way to change these images at this point. I'm running this in Corona Lua if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Well, TexturePacker will put many images into one - if they fit well. So if you got multiple small images, like on the sprite sheet below, it's a save!

[image: multiple images packed into one sheet]

However, having dozen of large images (1024x768 ones) and trying to fit them to a square of 2048x2048 won't bring you to success - you can fit 4 of them into a single sheet, I think not many more. Unless you got the borders with transparency, then the TexturePacker magic can "trim" the edges and put the images a bit tighter. Still won't give you 48 images packed there :)

I would say - don't use a single sprite sheet for all your images. Instead try to think about it - which ones should I display at once, on one scene? So you can put a background + some additional objects and fit them, for example, into a 1024x1024 size - this would be an actual save

Below you can see a sprite sheet from one of my games - it includes 2 full-screen (iPhone size) graphics for the backgrounds and a bunch of objects that are placed on top of those.

[image]

Comment: Does TexturePacker have a "multipacking" feature, or do we have to do it manually?

Comment: @SteveSmith do you know the answer to that question? I am also wondering if we have to do it manually. I'd really like not to!

Comment: @TheForgot3n1 Sorry, no, it was so long ago, I don't think I've even used TexturePacker for about 4 years now.